# Why is the Artin-Rees lemma used here?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am currently engaged in independent study of algebraic geometry, using Dan Bump's book. One of the exercises in it outlines a proof of the Krull Intersection Theorem, which [here] is the following:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and let $M$ be the intersection of all of the $\mathfrak{m}^n$. Then $M = 0$.

The hints direct me to use the Artin-Rees lemma to show that $\mathfrak{m} M = M$, then use Nakayama's lemma to show that $M = 0$ (this second step is easy). I showed this to a professor and he accused the book of using big machinery for no reason, arguing that

$$\mathfrak{m} M = \mathfrak{m} \bigcap_{n \ge 0} \mathfrak{m}^n = \bigcap_{n \ge 1} \mathfrak{m}^n = M.$$

Does this argument work? Does Bump apply Artin-Rees because that argument works in some broader context where the above argument fails?

Comment: Don't believe everything that professors tell you. How did he show that $m\bigcap m^n=\bigcap m^{n+1}$?

Comment: @user3120: no problem.  It's clear that m times the intersection of the m^n is contained in the intersection of the m^{n+1}, but there is no reason to expect the reverse inclusion in general.  I don't know a counterexample off the top of my head, though.

Comment: Yeah, I don't recall the argument he gave. Will hunt for a counterexample.

Comment: Incidenally, the Artin--Rees Lemma is not particlarly heavy machinery: it is a direct application of the Hilbert Basis Theorem (although not always explained this way), which makes it a pretty basic and fundamental fact about Noetherian rings.

Comment: $(x^2) \cap (x) = (x^2) \neq (x^3)$ which is the product of the ideals inside $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Answer (score 6):

There is a proof due to Herstein that is "elementary" in the sense of avoiding the Artin-Rees lemma. Below is Kaplansky's presentation of this proof, from his "Commutative Rings". A proof using primary decomposition (as in Krull's original proof) can be found in Zariski and Samuel.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

See Theorem 3.6 in Chapter 6 of the [CRing project](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~amathew/CRing.pdf) for another elementary argument due to Perdry (American Math. Monthly, 2004) using only the Hilbert basis theorem. In fact, it shows more: if $R$ is a noetherian domain, $I \subset R$ a proper ideal, then the intersection of the powers of $I$ is trivial.

Comment: Dear Akhil, Nice.  Of course, my fondness for Artin--Rees forces me to point out that this is very close to just a reproof of that lemma in this particular case.  Best wishes,

Comment: @Matt: Dear Matt, I agree, given that -- as you observe -- the Artin-Rees lemma is essentially a statement about the noetherianness of a polynomial ring.

Comment: Perdry's proof is also given in my commutative algebra notes: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf.  This is one of the most remarkable instances of a quick, easy proof of a nontrivial theorem that I know.

Comment: @Akhil: the end of your proof of Artin-Rees is rather unorthodox: "This is easy to check, but we're out of
time.  We'll talk about this more next week."

Comment: By the way, I encountered this CRing project about a week ago while googling for other online notes in commutative algebra to post to the webpage for my commutative algebra course.  It's quite impressive.  I certainly take it as serious competition to my notes.  It might be worth chatting at some point to carve out complementary paths...

Comment: @Pete: Dear Pete, yes, the project is very unfinished right now and frequently reflects its origins in a set of notes. Thank you for your kind words (and for the link on your website!). We should indeed chat sometime about complementary paths. Right now I (at least) envision the CRing project as taking a heterodox stance for functoriality and universal properties (kind of like the book "Algebraic topology from a homotopical viewpoint"). I also have had great fun surfing old issues of the Monthly to look for material to add.