# Why ring with only even numbers is not an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $S$ be a set of all even integers. According to my text book, $(S,+,\cdot)$ is a **ring** which is not an **integral domain**. It is stated as a fact without an explanation and I fail to see the reason for this.

Why the ring from above is not an integral domain?

EDIT:
It can't be because of the lack of $1$ element. In the next example, $(Z,+,\cdot)$ (where $Z$ is the whole set of integers) is stated to be an integral domain.

Comment: Some (not all)  definitions do not even allow this to be a ring since it lacks a multiplicative unit.

Comment: It is better to be more specific than "It is stated as a fact..." Who stated it? What definitions is that person/book/notes using?

Comment: I'm not sure why your edit shows anything. $\mathbb Z$ has a multiplicative identity, so how does that contradict anything?

Comment: Ohh, I can see it now. I thought that the multiplicative identity has to be denoted in the ring definition $(Z,+,\cdot,1,0)$. But now I get what you meant (that 1 is not even).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that your book's definition of *integral domain* requires a multiplicative identity element, which $(S,+,\cdot)$ does not have.

Comment: and here's a thread explaining why: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/why-is-an-integral-domain-a-commutative-ring-with-unity

Comment: @exitingcorpse: Thanks! I was just about to look for that.

Comment: Please see my edit.. It is possible that my book is simply wrong.

Comment: @jakubka: $(\Bbb Z,+,\cdot)$ has a multiplicative identity element, but aside from that, there's no property that distinguishes it from $(S,+,\cdot).$ This suggests even *more* strongly to me that your book means that $(S,+,\cdot)$ isn't an integral domain **precisely** because it doesn't have a multiplicative identity.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. $\mathbb{Z}$ contains 1, but $S$ doesn't. Thanks a lot for the answer!